# PHP Email Form, Executes but Only Sends to 'Some' Email Services

Tags: php, forms, email

I'm developing a simple email contact form which currently executes without errors and displays the success message I added.

However after testing it, the email is only received by a Microsoft Outlook address I have.

Gmail, Hotmail and Yahoo don't receive the message, and it was Gmail I was aiming for mostly.

I have checked the Spam/Junk folders in each case and no sign.

If anyone has any ideas why this is the case it would be great. I didn't post code as it does work in at least one instance, but here is the format for the 'headers' if that helps.

```
 $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
 'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
 @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
```

Comment: have u hard coded the $email_to so that it is sending to a same address code will be usefull here . i had this problem this week and i hardcoded .  check if ur passing an array to for email ids

Comment: yes the $email_to has been hardcoded for each time I've tested it, what's my alternative there? no array is being passed, just values for 'name', 'email address' and 'comments'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the same code works to send email to one recipient, but not another, then the problem is with the recipients.

I suspect that it's because the recipients' email providers think your emails look like spam.

I'd recommend getting rid of the `Reply-to` header, and putting the address in the `From` field, for one thing - basically, the more you can do to make your emails look less like spam, the better.

If that doesn't work, try sending as limited a message as you can using your code - no extra header information added, no links in the text - and if that works, slowly start adding things back in until you stop getting the messages.

Comment: Seems like a more realistic cause of the problem, I'll have a play with it and get back to you.

Comment: It's frustrating that just about all the things you do as a coder to make emails you're sending useful and informative are also used by spammers to make their emails more deceptive....

Comment: After removing the headers section altogether it wouldn't work in any email service. I then added it back in and removed the Reply-to line, the email in this case is still received by Outlook, but still nothing in Gmail. Any other ideas? Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: All I can suggest is that you put as little in the headers as you can - 'From' should do it - and a short, plain text message. If that doesn't get through, then there's something happening elsewhere that is flagging your emails as spammish - maybe another user on your ISP with a compromised PC, sending out spam using your ISP's mailservers.

Answer (score 0):

then add the email whom u want to mail either it is gmail or yahoo  to field of $email_to where u have hard coded it

or if you are passing you email dynmaically from a form then set it has

$email_to = $_post['email'];

then add it to your header then it should go to the recipient .

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible that the IP you are sending from has been blacklisted (if your server is on a shared IP, somebody using that IP has sent some bad stuff).

Try from a different IP address if possible, if it works then you know the problem and can complain to your webhost.

Comment: Blacklisted by one email service and not another? It's a home IP so I'm pretty there's no issue there though.

Comment: yeah, they don't share a blacklist. Are you using a service like AOL that shares IP addresses between their users? Also, you're sending this from your localhost? If so, try it on a web server.